# Ruby Regex to keep single apostrophe but remove end apostrophes

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, string

For the following string, how can I get rid of the enclosing single quotes?

```
string: "'won't'"
desired result: "won't"
```

looking for a regex expression that I can use in `gsub` to replace `''` with empty string. e.g.

```
arr = ["'don't'", "stop", "str%&eaming"]
arr.map { |letter| gsub(/pattern/, ""}
```

should return

```
=> ["don't", "stop", "streaming"]
```

Comment: Could you have a string, `"'don't' or "'won't'"` or is it always just one word with three single quotes/apostrophes? If that character appears between two letters is it necessarily an apostrophe (to be kept)?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in irb

```
arr.map { |l| l.gsub(/^'|'$|%&/, '') }
```

Note that this will not modify the original way. To destructively mutate the array, you will need to use a `bang` method, in this case `arr.map!`.

Here is a simple explanation.

In the regex, we are searching for matches that either start or end with an apostrophe, or that contain the two special characters in the third item.

The symbol `^` is used to indicate the line begins with a certain substring. On the other hand, the symbol `$` is used to indicate a line ending with a certain substring. The `|` operator is common in Computer Science to represent an `or` conditional.

However, if you have a string that spans multiple lines, you should consider using the `\A` and `\z` expressions to indicate the start and end of a string.

My output in irb is as follows

```
=> ["don't", "stop", "streaming"]
```

Comment: I like how easily solution can scale, i.e. if they want to replace the single quotes between words like `"don't' stop" (although not part of the OP yet)  this could be modified from `^'|'$` to `^'|'$|'\s`

Comment: `^` means beginning of *line*, not *string* in Ruby; similarly for `$` at the other end. You almost always want `\A` and `\z` in Ruby.

Comment: A problem: `"'twas".gsub(/^'|'$|%&/, '') #=>  "twas"`.

Comment: `%&` was an example of non-word characters. If I would want to filter all non-word characters, how would I edit the regex ...
`arr.map { |l| l.gsub(/^'|'$|\W/, '') }` - this didn't work
`arr.map { |l| l.gsub(/^'|'$|[\.!&*:,@$%^], '') }` - this does

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple.

```
def strip_single_quotes(str)
  str[0]=="'" && str[-1]=="'" ? str[1..-2] : str
end

arr = ["'don't'", "stop", "str%&eaming", "'twas", "''twas'", "'fishin''", "she'd've"]

arr.each { |word| puts "#{word.ljust(12)} -> #{strip_single_quotes(word) }" }
'don't'      -> don't
stop         -> stop
str%&eaming  -> str%&eaming
'twas        -> 'twas
''twas'      -> 'twas
'fishin''    -> fishin'
she'd've     -> she'd've
```

You could instead write the body of `strip_single_quotes` as follows.

```
str =~ /\A'.*'\z/ ? str[1..-2] : str
```